# TIUSB3410 Linux Driver

Tags: linux, usb, driver, raspbian, texas-instruments

I am trying desperately to communicate from Linux (Raspbian kernel 4.4.12-v7+) with a device that uses the TIUSB3410 USB part.

Here is the output from dmesg:

```
[ 2730.016013] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[ 2730.161030] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=3410
[ 2730.161049] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2730.161062] usb 1-1.4: Product: TUSB3410 Boot Device
[ 2730.161074] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[ 2730.161087] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: TUSB3410        
[ 2730.164670] ti_usb_3410_5052 1-1.4:1.0: TI USB 3410 1 port adapter converter detected
[ 2730.164793] usb 1-1.4: Direct firmware load for ti_usb-v0451-p3410.fw failed with error -2
[ 2730.164934] usb 1-1.4: ti_download_firmware - firmware too large 37874
[ 2730.164986] ti_usb_3410_5052: probe of 1-1.4:1.0 failed with error -5
```

I have searched high and low for information and nothing works. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 
I am using the latest Raspbian kernel 4.4.12-v7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question:

I am running a raspberry pi model 3 with the latest debian kernel 4.4.13.
I downloaded the latest source, ran make menuconfig, and most importantly enabled USB TI 3410/5052  Serial Driver located here:

```
Device Driver --->
    [*] USB support --->
        [*] USB Serial Converter support --->
            <*> USB TI 3410/5052 Serial Driver
```

It is important to enable each level above by pressing Y to include in the kernel. In my example having the feature modularized M did NOT work.

I followed the instructions here to configure and build the kernel:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

Comment: Was it enough to get fw file into taget filesystem? Or where is the fw file coming from?

Comment: Yes, I was able to communicate with the target device.

Comment: fw file was part of kernel build after that? Or needed to be downloaded separately?

Comment: I do not remember what messages were in dmesg after the rebuild. I was able to communicate from my system to the target system which contained the TI part using a serial interface. That probably means the direct fw load was successful.